# Git Hook Force branch to be rebased before it is merged and pushed on develop

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

In our project, we have a develop branch. We have half a dozen developers who are free to push to develop, but we've asked them to rebase their feature branches on top of the develop before they do the merge.

Occasionally, people forget to do this and it creates an uglier merge history on develop.

Is there a hook on git , we can use to prevent merges on develop without making a rebase on their workplace ?

This hook could be set on a client's side, not server side means that for all projects we can put the hook in the .git/hooks.

Thanks,

Comment: Is this what you are looking for, maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32657757/force-feature-branch-to-be-rebased-before-it-is-merged-or-pushed

Comment: Why was my answer added like a comment?